# matplotlib: unknown property hold

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using python/matplotlib and I am trying to hold the figure and plt.hold(True) seems to be deprecated.

The below command gives me "AttributeError: Unknown property hold"

```
ax.plot(x, y, z, hold=True, c='r', marker='.')
```

What's the alternative, or what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `hold` was deprecated, `plot` behaves as if `hold=True`, so you can leave out specifying it explicitly.